# vertical align a "button"

Tags: html, css

I´ve made a transparent "button" and place it on a fullwidth background image 
 I use the class in an `<a>`
I would like the button to be centered responsively on the image. I got it done horizontally but not exactly vertically. (My idea is to make a one page type a page)
Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="nav">nav area</div>
            <div class="bg-image">
              <a class="button-transp abs" href="#">Butt text<br>second line<br>third</a>
                <img src="bg_top.jpg">
                 <h1>This is centered text.</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="main">main area</div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
margin: 25% auto 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.button-transp {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}
```

I use margin: 25% auto 0; to get it something near right..

Answer (score 0):

You wanted the button to stay center responsively to the image, which, in this case you should use **background image**. Then position your button to be **50% from the top**, **50% from the left** and **pull it back -1/2 of its height to the top** and **-1/2 of its width to the left**. Doing this to enforce the button to always stay in the center of the `bg-image`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">nav area</div>
    <div class="bg-image">
       <a class="button-transp abs" href="#">Butt text<br>second line<br>third</a>
       <h1>This is centered text.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">main area</div>
</div>

.abs {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -37px;  /** the button height is 74, so pull it half to the top the make the gap top and bottom equal */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -95px; /** again, full button width / 2 */
}
.button-transp {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 170px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}
.bg-image {
    background: url(http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 475px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy1adqw/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I meant responsively to screen. The image is never really fully shown. And I also cannot fix the size of the button because content /text will change

Answer (score 0):

I've abbreviated the structure but this option will work for any size button and will always center both horizontally & vertically.

CSS3 transforms are basically IE9 and up (suitably prefixed as required)

```css
.bg-image {
    height: 200px;
    background: orange;
    position: relative; /* positioning contexr */
}

.button-transp {
    width: 30%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bg-image">
        <a class="button-transp abs" href="#">Butt text<br/>second line<br/>third</a>
    </div>
</div>
```